# rate for dragging when selecting text?

Tags: javascript, html, gsap

Does this community have any insight regarding the rate (pixels/second) at which content in a scrollable element moves when selecting text and dragging beyond the element's container?

For example, if you select some text from the top here with your mouse:
http://www.gutenberg.org/files/52521/52521-0.txt
and then drag down out of the browser window, your selection is automagically extended while you scroll.  Moves a little slower when you are closer to the boundaries.  Seems to reach a maximum velocity at a certain distance.

I want to know what the rules for that scroll rate are.  I want to re-create that functionality with an animation library (e.g. greensock).

Tech note: the reason I want to re-create it and not use that functionality 'out-of-the-box' from the browser is that for other reasons I need to return false / preventDefault on the mouseDown event.  This prevents the auto-scrolling.

Comment: The site can't be reached, your URL is broken.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that rate will vary dramatically by browser and operating system.